# how to rename a file received via intent filters in android development

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to rename an Microsoft Word file within my android application that is  coming from intent filters how do i accomplish that in android studio? I have looked at different sort of related answers could not find any

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: u sent a link about the File Class how do to i actually implement the logic  given the onCreate method with an activity called from the intent filters ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the specific set of `<intent-filter>` element you are using for your `<activity>`.

Comment: My Manifest   <activity android:name=".APKHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name ="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data  android:mimeType="application/msword"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

Comment: My activity  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apkhandler);

        

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){
            handleIntent(intent);
        }

    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

            
    }

Comment: Please note that there is an "edit" link under your question. Rather than posting code in comments, edit the question and add the code there.